# limit the number of months in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a dataset, output of a sql query which  gives me the below output :

```
Year Month  TotalSales  TotalProducts
2013   1          23233           45
2013   2           3344           43
2013   3             232             11
2013   4            2232           23
```

I am trying to represent the above dataset in a table and a bar graph using SSRS.

Is there a way I can limit the months to the last three months on SSRS ??

I am using the current month as a parameter in SSRS.

So example : I choose month 4 as a parameter , i would like to see the results only for the months 4,3 & 2 in the bar chart and the table

Is there a way I can do it ?

The actual query looks something like this :

```
SELECT ISNULL(x.[Month],z.[Month]) AS [Month],  
       ISNULL(x.Sum_Stores, 0) - ISNULL(y.Sum_SalesStores, 0) AS Difference , ISNULL(Sum_onetonine, 0) as EcontractsbetweenOneandNine........................
FROM   
(
    SELECT [Month], Sum(Stores) AS Sum_Stores 
    FROM   SUM_XXX 
    WHERE  [Year] = '2013' and Name = 'Pro'
    GROUP BY [Month]
) AS x
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT [Month], Sum(tracts) AS Sum_SalesStores 
    FROM   SUM_yyy 
    WHERE  [Year] = '2013' and Name = 'Pro'
    GROUP BY [Month]
) AS y ON x.[Month] = y.[Month] 
............................
```

Comment: can you show the actual query that get you this result set ?

Comment: @courage if the month chosen < 3 do you need to see previous year e.g. if month 1 is selected do you need month 11 and 12 of prev year?

Comment: @Muhammed Ali : I updated the query for my dataset.

Comment: @TI: Yes I would like to see the 11 and 12 of previous year too.. but for now let me know if you have a solution that works for the same year  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @ParamDate DateTime =null; -- Pass the required date in datetime format
                                   -- as per your example pass @ParamDate as '20130401'
SET @ParamDate = getdate(); --setting the current date for demo purpose

SELECT ISNULL(x.[Month],z.[Month]) AS [Month],  
       ISNULL(x.Sum_Stores, 0) - ISNULL(y.Sum_SalesStores, 0) AS Difference , ISNULL(Sum_onetonine, 0) as EcontractsbetweenOneandNine........................
FROM   
(
    SELECT [Month], Sum(Stores) AS Sum_Stores 
    FROM   SUM_XXX 
    WHERE  ([Year] = year(@ParamDate) or [Year] = year(dateadd(m,-2,@ParamDate)) )
            and ([Month] = month(@ParamDate) or [Month] = month(dateadd(m,-2,@ParamDate)) )
            and Name = 'Pro'
    GROUP BY [Month]
) AS x
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT [Month], Sum(tracts) AS Sum_SalesStores 
    FROM   SUM_yyy 
    WHERE  ([Year] = year(@ParamDate) or [Year] = year(dateadd(m,-2,@ParamDate)) )
            and ([Month] = month(@ParamDate) or [Month] = month(dateadd(m,-2,@ParamDate)) )
            and Name = 'Pro'
    GROUP BY [Month]
) AS y ON x.[Month] = y.[Month] 
............................
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this in SSRS.

Do you want to limit the results returned by the query if so use a query parameter [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157187.aspx)

Or you can apply a filter to the dataset / dataregion [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239395.aspx)

What you will essentially want to do would be (pseudo)

```
DataSet!Month.Value BETWEEN Parameter!Month.Value-2 AND Parameter!Month.Value
```

That doesn't take into considertion months 1 and 2 properly. Will update when I have a better solution then a convoluted `if-else`.

Edit: If you added a `MonthStart` field to the result set as a proper `DATETIME` and used `MonthStart` as values to the parameter then you could do

```
DataSet!Month.Value BETWEEN DATEADD (MONTH, -2, Parameter!Month.Value) AND Parameter!Month.Value
```